# Curl a URL list from a file and make it faster with parallel

Tags: url, curl, gnu-parallel

Right now i'm using the followin code:

```
while read num;
    do M=$(curl "myurl/$num")
    echo "$M"
done < s.txt
```

where s.txt contains a list (1 per line) of a part of the url.

Is it correct to assume that curl is running sequentially?
Or is it running in thread/jobs/multiple conn at a time?

I've found this online:

```
 parallel -k curl -s "http://example.com/locations/city?limit=100\&offset={}" ::: $(seq 100 100 30000) > out.txt
```

The problem is that my sequence is coming from a file or from a variable (one element per line) and i can't adapt it to my needs

I've not fully understood how to pass the list to parallel

Should i save all the curl commands in the list and run it with parallel -a ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
parallel -j100 -k curl myurl/{} < s.txt
```

Consider spending an hour walking through `man parallel_tutorial`. Your command line will love you for it.

Comment: Phone typo sorry. Is it running 100 curl at a time? If so will it wait for all those 100 to end or it will maintain 100 of them till the end?

Comment: Consider spending an hour walking through man parallel_tutorial. Your command line will love you for it.